# How to get a blur in effect after a blur out effect on an underlying Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have put together a blur out/in effect for a landing page. However it is not quite working how it is supposed too and i am not sure why.

It blurs out fine, The problem lies on when i want the underlying Div to appear, i would like that to "fade in", as it stands it just appears after the fade out has finished.

Here is a snippet:

```js
splash = document.getElementById('intro');
content = document.getElementById('content');

 function enterSite (element) {
  opac = 1;
  fps = 1000/30;
  function decrease() {
   opac -= 0.02;
   if (opac <= 0.1){
    splash.style.display = 'none';
    return true;
   }
  splash.style.opacity = opac;
  setTimeout(decrease,fps);
  }
  function increase() {
   opac += 0.02;
   if (opac >= 0.1){
    content.style.display = 'block';
    return false;
   }
  content.style.opacity = opac;
  setTimeout(increase,fps);
  }
  decrease(), increase();
 }
```

```css
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
#intro {
    background-image: url(Images/splash.jpg);   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
#splash {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(56,56,56,0.4);
    border-radius: 50px 50px;
}
#splash-p {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn {
    width: 35%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Main Content Page */

article {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="intro">
   <div id="splash">

   <p id="splash-p">Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing.</p> 

   <input type="image" src="Images/Button.png" class="btn" onclick="enterSite()">

   </div>
  </div>

  <article id="content">
   
   Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,Just a random piece of online text that means nothing,

  </article>

 </main>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, The "typo" did not change anything, it is still exactly the same before i adjusted the "typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could benefit from breaking things out a little bit more and not nesting so many functions and calls. Also, it may be helpful to use a `setInterval()` instead of repeating `setTimeout()`.

```
splash = document.getElementById('intro');
content = document.getElementById('content');
var fadeOut = null;
var fadeIn = null;
opac = 1;
fps = 1000/30;

function increase() {
    content.style.opacity = opac;
    opac += 0.02;

    if (opac >= 1){ //Opacity is 100%
      window.clearInterval(fadeIn); //Stop fade-in
    }

}

function decrease() {
    splash.style.opacity = opac;
    opac -= 0.02;

    if (opac < 0.1){ //If object is almost gone
        splash.style.display = 'none'; //Hide it completely
        window.clearInterval(fadeOut); //Stop fade-out

        content.style.display = 'block'; //Set up new content
        content.style.opacity = 0;
        fadeIn = setInterval(increase, fps); //Begin fade-in

    }
}

function enterSite () {
    fadeOut = setInterval(decrease, fps); //Start the fadeout
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d4nnto29/)

Comment: That doesn't work either. The main content still just appears. And really do not wish to be working with Jquery, I haven't learnt that yet

Comment: @Ricky please review now.